# Unity game on android cannot find or read XML file

Tags: c#, android, xml, unity-game-engine

I have a game made in Unity that I'm trying to deploy on Android devices. I'm trying to use XML files to store information on the device, but the problem is that when the game is on any Android device it cannot find the XML file path correctly.

In order to read it I'm using the XML serializer (http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer) and I just want to know if there's anything that I need to do in order to get the actual file path of the XML file.

I've tried using a streaming assets method so I have a folder called streaming assets with the XML file I want to read in it.  I tried using this code to try and access it (My ItemContainer works the same way as the MonsterContainer):

```
string path;
ItemContainer itemCollection;
if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
    path = "file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "!/assets/" + _xmlFile.name + ".xml";
} else {
    path = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/" + _xmlFile.name + ".xml";
    itemCollection = ItemContainer.Load(path);
}
```

This however didn't work on Android but did work on my Windows desktop. Then I saw that WWW might be able to be used for finding the file, but again it didn't work:

```
string path;
ItemContainer itemCollection;
if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
    path = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + _xmlFile.name;
    WWW data = new WWW(path);
    StartCoroutine(MyRead(data));
    itemCollection = ItemContainer.Load(data.text);
} 
else {
    path = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/" + _xmlFile.name + ".xml";
    itemCollection = ItemContainer.Load(path);
}
```

Is there anything missing or anything that I'm doing wrong in order to access the XML file on Android devices?

[Edit]
I found out a small problem that was making the enumerator not work so I've redone how the program accesses the file a bit so that it's more in line with what some of the suggestions have hinted at

```
private void XMLSerializerLoad()
{
    string path;
    path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/assets/" + _xmlFile.name + ".xml";
    StartCoroutine(MyRead(path));
}

IEnumerator MyRead(string path)
{
    ItemContainer _items;
    WWW www = new WWW(path);
    yield return www;
    _items = ItemContainer.LoadFromText(www.text);
    _spelling_words = new List<Item>(); //Setting to an empty list
    _spelling_words = _items._items;
}
```

But when I run this I get:

XmlException: Document did not appear. Line 1 position 1.

Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read()

Answer (score 0):

Application.streamingAssetsPath in Android already contains file:// so you need to omit that in android in order for it to work.

```
  path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "!/assets/" +   _xmlFile.name + ".xml";
```

It's the same for Application.dataPath you do not need to add file:// or jar:file://

I don't understand what ! is for, in "!/assets/" maybe that ca be a problem too

Comment: Unfortunately, what you've suggested hasn't worked. I build my game for android deployment and it fails to do what I want it to when I press a button that is supposed to run the method that uses the information that it took from the XML file

Comment: would it help if I tried to make a quick project that's designed to illustrate my problem instead of describe what's going wrong?

Comment: Streaming assets folder is not really for saving things . Use Application.dataPath + _xmlFilename.xml  for saving. And are you sure the file exists there? maybe you have not created it yet and you try to open it for reading . consider checking its existence

Comment: I have made multiple copies of the file in any possible location that it could be in so I don't understand how it can't find the file. Also I'm not saving, the whole point is I'm trying to read the file and apparently I can only use StreamingAssets path but from what you're saying the only thing that I could possibly do to make this right is to make a script that crates a file in datapath location and load everything I want in it by the program