# Unity 3D using WWW class to read xml to pass into xml deserializer

Tags: c#, android, xml, serialization, unity-game-engine

So I had a question on here recently about how my xml file couldn't be found on my android device ([Unity game on android cannot find or read XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169311/unity-game-on-android-cannot-find-or-read-xml-file)) I now have it able to find the file using the WWW Class and using Application.streamingAssetsPath, with this I have now managed to make it access the file and run it through an xml deserializer (http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer). However, the program still refuses to find the file on my Android device. My Question is: Where did I go wrong?

Code for finding and reading file (Deserializing is the same as the link):

```
private void XMLSerializerLoad()
{
    string path;
    path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/assets/" + _xmlFile.name + ".xml";
    print("Loading from: " + path);
    StartCoroutine(MyRead(path));
}

IEnumerator MyRead(string path)
{
    ItemContainer _items;
    print("Access file: " + path);
    WWW www = new WWW(path);
    yield return www;
    _items = ItemContainer.Load(www.url);
    _spelling_words = new List<Item>(); //Setting to an empty list
    _spelling_words = _items._items;
}
```

Note: _spelling_words is a global list of type Item which contains a string for the word, an int for the year group and a string for the description of the word

[Edit]

I also decided to use 7-zip to try and extract the apk to find the file path and found that the file is in fact inside the assets directory inside of the apk AND there's another assets directory inside of that is the same xml file again, I expected that because of how I structured the streaming assets folder

[Edit]

XML example:

```
    <word name="WINNER">
    <year>2</year> >
    <Description>A person that wins</Description>
    </word>

    <word name="HUGE">
    <year>2</year>
    <Description>Extraordinary large in quantity</Description>
    </word>

    <word name="TRUE">
    <year>2</year>
    <Description>The opposite of false</Description>
    </word>

    <word name="GREW"> 
    <year>2</year> >
    <Description>Past tense of grow</Description>
    </word>
```

Serializer Example

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string _name;
    [XmlElement("year")]
    public int _year;
    [XmlElement("Description")]
    public string _description;
}

[XmlRoot("spelling_game")]
public class ItemContainer
{
    [XmlArray("words"), XmlArrayItem("word")]
    public List<Item> _items = new List<Item> ();

    public void Save(string path)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemContainer));
        using(var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
        }
    }

    public static ItemContainer Load(string path)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemContainer));
        using(var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as ItemContainer;
        }
    }

    public static ItemContainer LoadFromText(string text) 
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemContainer));
        return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text)) as ItemContainer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you are using `XmlSerializer`.  Can you share that?

Comment: Also, can you show an example of the XML you want to read?

Comment: I've added in the requested code